# Error message: The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled

Tags: flutter

Can help me. Error message is The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled.
Try using a list literal, 'List.filled' or 'List.generate'.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a new empty list like

```dart
 List<TextEditingController> _controllers = [];
```

> [`List()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/List/List.html) constructor cannot be used in null-safe code. Use List.filled to create a non-empty list. This requires a fill value to initialize the list elements with. To create an empty list, use [] for a growable list or List.empty for a fixed length list (or where growability is determined at run-time).

More about [list class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/List-class.html).

Comment: How bout this _functionalAndCognitiveStatusDescriptionControllers = new List(); to fix error I need to change like that? _functionalAndCognitiveStatusDescriptionControllers = [];

Comment: Yes, you are right.